# Good name for "URL-friendly title"?

Tags: seo, friendly-url, slug

I'm creating a dynamic website with articles. Each article has a title, like "How does one eat a dog and live with it?", but also something I'm now calling "URL Friendly Title", such as "eating-a-dog".

I'm looking for a better word for "URL Friendly Title", because it's quite a mouthful. Wordpress calls them "Post Slug" but I dislike that too much. What would be a good name for these things?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going for "Identifier"

Answer (score 17):

I'm sorry to say that "slug" really does seem to be the standard term. [Here is](http://writerway.blogspot.com/2007/04/slugs-on-web.html) somewhat of an [etymology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etymology) on the term, it seems it comes from the (oldschool, print) [news business](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slug_%28production%29).

Comment: Yuk, how could they pick something this ugly :p

Comment: yeah slug is a term of good pedigree, not slimy at all, and the defacto term for this concept

Comment: Don't know if English speakers find this obvious. Not being one, I've only recently found out that the title part of "friendly" URI is called slug. For me first thing that comes into mind when I hear word "slugs" are ugly shell-less snail and a type of shotgun ammo.

Comment: Guess I'll just have to live with slug then. I wish it were different, but it's no use going against the standard.

Answer (score 5):

You could attempt to not give it a name and instead show how it would be used. So instead of having something like this:

```
Title              : _______
URL Friendly Title : _______
```

you could have

```
Title : _______
URL   : http://yourdomain.com/articles/______
```

Comment: Not a complete solution in all cases, but definitely a good idea which I will apply where possible.

Answer (score 1):

You could have

Natural Name = "How does one eat a dog and live with it?"
and
URL Name = "eating-a-dog"

Answer (score 1):

How about "short-name"?
Near the entry field it would be a good idea to make it clear what this is by giving an example of how the short-name would appear in a url.

Comment: Shortname isn't that bad, but in my eyes a short name could also be something like "Eating a dog" which isn't URL-friendly

Comment: In that case, perhaps replace spaces and non-url friendly characters for the user thus making t instantly more user friendly? That way, the user doesn't have to worry about formatting the url name - they just need to enter a "short name" for the article.

Answer (score 0):

I think the choice should be determined by the type of end users of your system. If it will be used by people who know the slang, go for *slug*, it is used in many CMSes.

If the software is designed for someone whose mission is to write text, and who are not familiar with tech-speak - then "slug" is a poor choice, because it rings no bells about the meaning of the feature. One will only figure it out by reading the manual, by asking someone else, or (most likely) by trial and error.

So my point is that you should go for a name that expresses the *meaning* of the feature, ex:

- friendly URL
- memorizable URL
- permanent link (something that is there forever, so it better be good)

I would also consider changing "URL" to "link" or "address", because "URL" could mean nothing to a newbie.

Regardless of your choice, you should:

- fill it with a reasonably good default value (generated from the entered title)
- show a preview

This enables people to understand what this field is for, without submitting the article and then observing what happened.

Answer (score 0):

i think the best would be to display it as

URL: site.com/article/**_**

And if it is really important that the URL is appropriate/descriptive/SEO Friendly, you can place a red exclamation mark or something eye-catching next to the label URL, when the user hovers over it you can have a little pop up speech bubble (for example) that explains how to write the slug (and maybe even a warning if they do not use an appropriate SEO friendly URL).

Answer (score -1):

How about "SEO Title"?

Comment: In my opinion, SEO is too techie for an average user.

Comment: I would have thought that nowadays, even if someone does not know what it stands for, there is some understanding of what it relates to. :)

Answer (score -1):

I call it "Friendly Name".